# Put bars inside of each other in SSRS, but not stacked

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

In SSRS in a bar chart, in order to save space I would like to put two bars inside of each other (or behind if you want to say so, but not stacked). How is that possible?
See example image.

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsvjA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the trick is to create a standard vertical column chart, then change the bigger bar's series to a range column chart. Then change the 'point width' attribute of each series to be different, so one bar fits in the other.